# How to display reviews from Amazon Products to Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, review, product-review, amazon

There is any option or extension is available, i want to display automatically my amazon products reviews to Magento 2 products accordingly ?

How to i can do this ? If there is any guide please share with me.

Thanks

Comment: https://elfsight.com/amazon-reviews-widget/magento/ - checkout this link

Answer (score 0):

Check the Extension for the same

https://elfsight.com/amazon-reviews-widget/magento/